# How to create webclient unit tests with Junit and Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-webflux

How can I create a unit test of this **private** method returning **void** using Junit4 and Mockito?

```
    private void fetchToken() {
        try {
        webClientBuilder.build().post().uri("http://localhost:8082/token")
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setBasicAuth("anyusername", "password")).retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Token.class).block();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: You can use wiremock and mock the responses for this token endpoint call. Is that a option for you ?

Comment: Yes, sounds good. Could you provide an example? @shubham

Comment: see my answer. i already showed you the idea how to do it which should be a good starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mockito like that

```
    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec uriSpec;
    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec headerSpec;


    @Test
    void someTest(){
            WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec bodySpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
            WebClient.ResponseSpec response = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
    
            when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(uriSpec);
            when(uriSpec.uri(uri)).thenReturn(headerSpec);
            doReturn(bodySpec).when(headerSpec).bodyValue(body);
            when(bodySpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(response);
    }
```

Comment: true but such "mock return mock and the returned mock return another mock which in turn this another mock return another mock which return another mock" is very ugly IMO..

Comment: Ugly? This is how mockito works. Andres asked about using Junit4 and Mockito, no other tools like wiremock for stubing request. By using mockito you have to mock every bean and you dont need to any other tools.. and the simply way is just write some factory for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response @viking but this is a private void method just wondering how can I write the assertion? How the assertion would look? For example, how can I assert that BasicAuth/BearerAuth is coming with the request?

Comment: You can verify argument with `arguemnt captor` for example`verify(bodySpec).header(headerCaptor.capture()))`

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner and less fragile approach is don't mock `WebClient` but mock the external API using tools [WireMock](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock) or [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

I usually used MockWebServer. You may say it is an integration test but not the unit test. But it term of speed , MockWebServer is very fast just like unit test. Moreover, it allows you to use the real `WebClient` instance to really exercise the full HTTP stack and you can be more confident that you are testing everything.

You can do something like :

```java
public class SomeTest {
    
    
    private MockWebServer server;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){

        MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start();
        HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/token");

        //stub the server to return the access token response
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("{\"access_token\":\"ABC\"}"));

       //continues execute your test
        ....

    }


}
```

Comment: Which maven dependency I need for MockWebServer? Also I read that this is more like an integration test as it’s communicating over an HTTP connection, so it’s not a unit test.

Comment: who care it is an unit test or integration test as long as the test is fast enough ,less fragile and more close to the actaul production codes?

Comment: What maven dependency/dependencies do I need to install?

Comment: see this (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/mockwebserver/4.10.0)